# JQuery .toggleClass if "0.00" value?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a function in that would make all text boxes a css `.class` if the value is `0.00`. Here's what I got...

```
$(':input[type="text"]').live 
(function() {
    if ($(this).val('0.00'))
    $(this).toggleClass('fieldFocus');  
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[type="text"]').live 
('blur', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '0.00'){
        $(this).toggleClass('fieldFocus');  
    }
});
```

in this case you have to attach a focusout event to your inputs and  `$(this).val() == '0.00'` is the right condition to check

Comment: Thank you, but it only works on .blur what about if I want it to just be a class when the value = 0.00?

Comment: the use the following code
`$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':text').filter(function() {
  return $(this).val() == '0.00';
}).toggleClass('fieldFocus');
});`

Comment: Almost. What I'm trying do do is also if the value changes the class is removed.

Comment: you want it as the user types or you want it on blur

Comment: I just want it to BE. Example: The form loads with the default values of 0.00. When the form gets calculated if that value changes the class gets applied. If the value goes back to 0.00, the class gets removed. The user may or may not ever click the box.

Comment: then you call the
`$(':text').filter(function() { return $(this).val() == '0.00'; }).toggleClass('fieldFocus');`

in the function that is calculating the form

Comment: Okay, I'll play around with that.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.each` to loop over the textboxes:

```
$(':text').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '0.00'))
      $(this).toggleClass('fieldFocus');
    }
});
```

Or if you want a bit more speed:

```
$(':text').filter(function() {
  return $(this).val() == '0.00';
}).toggleClass('fieldFocus');
```

But I doubt you want to loop over *all* the textboxes. What event or user interaction is this code supposed to fire on? A `click`, `hover`, `blur` (user clicks outside), etc?

---

Try this code:

```
$(':text').live('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '0.00'))
      $(this).toggleClass('fieldFocus');
    }
});

$(':text').change();
```

Comment: Nothing, it just is. All values on the page at all times if they are 0.00 need the .class applied. What the best way?

Comment: So you want the textboxes that have that value to have that class? See my update.

Comment: This only is working when the value is changed to 0.00. What about if the form loads, and the default value is 0.00, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`val(x)` sets a value and returns a jQuery object

`val()` returns the value.

Try `if ($(this).val() == '0.00')` instead